# Sending an SMS to all of your app users - how to?

Tags: android

I'm currently working on an android app that can be used by Admin to send sms messages to all users that installed my app. MustPls must I use cloud messaging or I can use my SQLite. But Ii need to use internet for sending the message. Would someone Pls can some one help me with advice or guidelines guidelines to accomplish this task? Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to send notification using SQLite. u can use FCM to send notification directly from firebase or generate notification from admin module and receive on user module. you have to use firebase any way.

Comment: Sir, i'm not sending notification. basically the app is messaging app, i want use it to be sending sms message using their phone numbers.

Comment: Technically, you could use push message from cloud to app, then If their phone numbers are available to the app you would need sms send permission and send one to them. But you could skip the whole I want your personal information and just create a notification instead. Otherwise you would need a system that sends sms messages and have their phone numbers in the cloud as well which also is increased problem if the numbers get stolen.

Comment: Thank for your support, however, the app has registration page that would allow a user to enter his name and phone number, so how can I get all users phone in an editText and used them as recipients for my SMS as SQLite is local to specific app.